# Constructing a quasiconvex function

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a nonempty convex set. A function $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called

- **convex** if 
  $$
  f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)\leq\lambda f(u)+(1-\lambda)f(v), \quad\forall u,v\in C, \forall\lambda\in(0,1);
  $$
- **quasiconvex** if
  $$
  f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)\leq\max\{f(u), f(v)\}, \quad\forall u,v\in C, \forall\lambda\in(0,1).
  $$

It is easy to very find that convexity implies quasiconvexity. The reverse implication is not true in general.

**Counterexample.** The function
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } \quad0<x<1, y=1, \\ 
1 & \mbox{if } \quad\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
is quasiconvex but  not convex on $C=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

- $f$ is not convex on $C$. Indeed, we have $(0.5,1), (0,0)\in C$ and
  $$
  f\left(\frac{1}{2}(0.5,1)+\frac{1}{2}(0,0)\right)=f(0.25,0.5)=1>0.5=\frac{1}{2}f\left(0.5,1\right)+\frac{1}{2}f(0,0).
  $$
- $f$ is quasiconvex on $C$. Indeed, let $u, v\in C$. We consider two cases:

**Case 1.** $u, v\in (0,1)\times\{1\}$

Then, $\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v\in  (0,1)\times\{1\}$ for all $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and so
$$
f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)=0=\max\{f(u),f(v)\};
$$

**Case 2.** $u\notin (0,1)\times\{1\}$ or $v\notin (0,1)\times\{1\}$

Then, $\max\{f(u),f(v)\}=1$, and so
$$
f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v)\leq\max\{f(u),f(v)\}, \quad \forall \lambda\in (0,1).
$$

**Question.**

We would like to construct a function $f(x,y):C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $C\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ being convex such that:

(1) $f(x,y)$ is not convex on $C$;

(2) $f(x,y)+\lambda y$ is quasiconvex on $C$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$
.

Thanks for all helping and comments.

Comment: I am waiting specialist in the field of applied mathematics to give some hints and comments to help me to solve this question.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220706/constructing-a-quasiconvex-function/1222000#1222000

Comment: @blindman I rapidly checked the crossposted question and answer in by Robert Israel within math.stackexchange. Could you clarify why it doesn't satisfy you there ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of convexity defined by a pair of means $(M,N)$:
$$
f(M(x,y))\le N(f(x),f(y)).
$$
You use special cases with weighted arithmetic and max&min means. This type of convexity is considered in a very good book:
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387243009

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you make clear you answer? I could not follow your ideas. Here, I would like to construct a function $f(x, y)$ satisfying (1) and (2).

Comment: After checking carefully the reference which you pointed out, I realized your solution is not related to my question.